# Assigning a vector to different positions in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a vector X:

```
X = c(1,21,2,7,4,22,19,15,30,1,2,6,9,22)
```

And I have 6 positions.

```
latitude = 1:3
longitude = 5:6
```

I want a data.table where all positions repeats the X vector.

I could do this:

```
dt = data.table::CJ(latitude,longitude,unique = TRUE)
dt = dt[,.(X=X),.(latitude,longitude)]
```

What if X is different for each position and you want to assign each vector to correct position
in a data table.

Here X is a cube. For each latitude and longitude there is a
X vector of length 5, e.g.,

```
X = array(1:30, c(3, 2, 5))
```

How would you do that? One way would be:

```
dt_coord = data.table::CJ(latitude,longitude,unique = TRUE)
X = array(1:30, c(3, 2, 5))
k = 1
dt_all = list()
for(lat in 1:3){
  for(lon in 1:2){
    dt_all[[k]] = data.table(longitude = dt_coord[k,longitude],
                             latitude = dt_coord[k, latitude],
                             X = X[lat,lon,])
    k = k + 1
  }
}

(dt = rbindlist(dt_all))
```

But I'd like to avoid loops. If latitude and longitude are big then this double loop would take forever. It's probably a clever way using merge or reshape or something :-)

## Added later:

There is a great solution below by @pseudospin.

Another solution could be:

```
dt3 = data.table(CJ(latitude,longitude,unique = TRUE),X = as.data.table(X)[,4])
```

Comment: What you are doing looks good. Do you need the unique? Can't the first example just be `CJ(latitude, longitude, X)`? Your second problem you've basically solved yourself `dt[,.(X=X[latitude, longitude, ]), .(latitude, longitude)]`

Comment: How did that cube come about in the first place?

Comment: @pseudospin Good point, thanks! I could just use the CJ but has to add sorted = FALSE otherwise it will sort the X vector and I do not want to change the order of that. The second problem with the cube I do not get to work using code unfortunately. I get subscripts out of bounds.

Comment: @sindri_baldur Not sure what you mean. Basically it is just an 3D array which needs to be converted to a data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do a loop for your extended example. Something like this.

```
CJ(i = seq_along(latitude), j = seq_along(longitude))[, 
  .(X = X[i, j, ]), .(i, j, latitude = latitude[i], longitude = longitude[j])][, 
    -c('i', 'j')]
```

Or you could just construct it directly,

```
data.table(
  latitude = latitude[rep(seq_along(latitude), length(longitude)*dim(X)[3])],
  longitude = longitude[rep(rep(seq_along(longitude), each = length(latitude)), dim(X)[3])],
  X = c(X)
)[order(latitude, longitude)]
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot. This is just what I was looking for and avoiding loops. Perfect.

Comment: I just realized my question is simply about converting an array to a data table so I could do this (still a bit clumsy):
dt3 = data.table(CJ(latitude,longitude,unique = TRUE),X = as.data.table(X)[,4])


Not sure if this would be slower than your proposal if the dimension of X was big, e.g., 360x180x125. I might time the three solutions and see which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not really clear to me.  However your sample case can be generated using the `expand.grid` function with clean-up that adds back the column names and sorts the columns to replicate `dt`.

```
dt2 <- expand.grid(latitude, longitude, X)
colnames(dt2) <- c('latitude', 'longitude', 'X')
dt2 <- arrange(dt2, latitude, longitude)
```

If each latitude and longitude has an associated vector `v1` and `v2` then would:

```
dt <- expand.grid(latitude, v1, longitude, v2)
```

work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. Not sure if this do the trick, but it might be because I'm not certain what you mean by associating a vector v1 and v2 to the latitude and longitude vectors. Latitude and longitude are vectors, so do you mean to associate a vector for each element in the latitude, longitude vectors - but without doing a loop?